# remove focus from blank textfield in extjs form

Tags: forms, extjs

how to remove focus (red border around textfield) from blank textfield in extjs form. Bydefault it gets focus on textfield.

Comment: What ExtJs version are you using? Also please post some code (for example how exactly your field is defined)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean resetting the textfield (removing text and clearing any validation messages, etc...)  you can use the reset method.

If your textfield id is myTextField then you should use:

```
Ext.getCmp('myTextField').reset();
```

Hope this helps.